# How to change the Upload size in Ubuntu server 14.10 running onwcloud

Tags: upload

I want to change the upload size from 513 to some bigger value

I have Ubuntu server 14.10 running onwcloud
PHP Version 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.3

I have checked my PHP version by:

1.Create a php file with  and open it with your browser

2.Change to 16G

/etc/php5/apache2 'php.ini'
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

PHP.ini above are the only one I have on my machine

3. Restar apache2

Still I get owncloud upload max 513MB

Is there anything else I have to do to change my upload size?

Answer (score 4):

What you did didn't work for you, because you have changed the wrong php.ini. The one you have changed is for the command line PHP.

The one that apache is using is located at

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Do not forget to restart apache after you have edited the file:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you enabled mod_rewrite you can also put this to your .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize = 16G
php_value post_max_size = 16G
```

To enable mod_rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

After that edit this file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deafult`, or if you have virtual hosts, edit the virtual host file to allow overriding. Find this lines:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

And change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`, or just add `AllowOverride All` under Directory tag if you does not have `AllowOverride None`

You can read the official article on owncloud documentation and how to change the upload limit [here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/admin_manual/configuration/big_file_upload_configuration.html).

Comment: That was a typo above

Comment: Can you check what are the loaded php.ini files with phpinfo()? Did you try the second method with .htaccess?

Comment: That was a typo above
I have also done it in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and that doesn't work

I have enabled mod_rewrite 

In this file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deafult I don't have 

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: I have it here /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/deafult-ssl.conf like this





<Directory /path/to/owncloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>






Should I change it here in the deafult-ssl.conf?


I was looking at owncloud guide before but I don't have 
.htaccess file

Comment: I have done as in the guide but this owncloud/.htaccess method because I don't have this file .htaccess

Comment: Just added this to sites-enabled/000-deafult and restarted apache but no difference










<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

How can I get .htaccess  in Ubuntu?

Comment: You can go to the owncloud folder and create new empty file just give it a name .htaccess. Also you can do it form terminal : `cd /path/to/your/owncloud && touch .htaccess` Then put those two lines in the file. Also do not forget to enable mod_rewrite as I described in the answer.

Comment: Getting closer

Just discovered I had this file .htaccess in the owncloud directory already but was a hidden file.


I have enabled mod_rewrite already


I have configured my php.ini and just changed the values in .htaccess from 513 (That's what was displaying in the admin page) to 16 G

php.ini and .htaccess

upload_max_filesize = 16G
post_max_size = 16G

Then service apache2 restart

But I wonder why I'm getting in the admin page Upload "max 203.6 GB" if I have added 16G?

Comment: @Carlos are you sure you are looking to upload file size and not to free space size? Anyway I'm happy that you finally managed to increase your upload file size.

Comment: Yes that's the Upload file size.  I was trying to upload 3G movie and I can see progress bar all the way to the end but then I get an "internal error message".  I think that certain hard limits that cannot be exceeded  < 2GB on 32Bit OS-architecture
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_files/big_file_upload_configuration.html

Comment: You are right the Upload max is going down as I upload stuff, it could be the free space

Comment: But this value was showing before as 513 MB in admin web page  and that is what was in .htaccess file for php_value upload_max_filesize = 513
php_value post_max_size = 513